# Find all occurrences of an expression in a file, even on the same line

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that has to be tailored; It contains "variables" that are represented by @variable.name@;
There may be more than one such variable on a line; and I want to find all of them.

My thought is that this should be possible with a sed regex, but most linux commands are at my disposal...

The regex I thought of was this one:
`s#(.*)(@.*@)(.*)#\2#`

However, that did not catch all...

Lets assume this file:

```
Dear @sirmadam@,

Today is @day@-@month@-@year@, a nice @weekday@day.
It is my @pleasureornot@ to tell you youre @hiredorsacked@.

Sincerely,
@nameoftheboss@
```

The output should be:

```
@sirmadam@
@day@
@month@
@year@
@weekday@
@pleasureornot@
@hiredorsacked@
@nameoftheboss@
```

I think my main issue is that the start and end of each variable uses the same sign, but there is little I can do about that... My regex-fu is lacking... I cant wrap my head around how this could be solved, it is a bit of a puzzle for me.

Comment: What about this: `(?<keyword>@.*?@)+` ? [Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/zAwpNS/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` works:

```sh
grep -o '@[^@]*@' foo.txt
```

By contrast, `sed` fundamentally works in a *line-based* fashion, and breaking out of this paradigm, while occasionally possible, is hard and usually indicates that another tool is better suited.

Comment: Suprt fast; this does exactly what I needed...  I tried grep, but obviously not with the [^@]